# Parse, best pattern to update array on User

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, parse-platform

In my app (iOS) I have a User class that is a subclass of PFUser. On the User object I have a list of video objects. The list is a history of videos the user has watched. Each time the users watches a video I want to add the video to the top of the list. If the video is already in the list I want to remove it from its current position and move it to the top. To do this I have the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *objectsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];

for(Video *v in self[VIDEO_HISTORY_KEY])
{
    if([v.videoId isEqualToString:video.videoId])
    {
        [objectsToRemove addObject:video];
    }
}

[self removeObjectsInArray:objectsToRemove forKey:VIDEO_HISTORY_KEY];

if(video.objectId)
{
    [self addObjectsFromArray:@[video] forKey:VIDEO_HISTORY_KEY];
    [self saveEventually];
}
else
{
    PFQuery *query = [Video query];
    [query whereKey:@"videoId" equalTo:video.videoId];

    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            if(object)
            {
                Video *videoToAdd = (Video *) object;
                [self addObjectsFromArray:@[videoToAdd] forKey:VIDEO_HISTORY_KEY];
            }
            else
            {
                [self addObjectsFromArray:@[video] forKey:VIDEO_HISTORY_KEY];
            }

            [self saveEventually];
        });
    }];
}
```

There are however many problems with this code.

1. It causes that app to crash. It seems like I can not remove objects from the list and add objects in the same update? If I remove the "removeObjectsInArray:" call the code kind of works.
2. When I start to loop over the videos in the history it crashes because the list is not populated from the backend yet. (self is the user class). So to make it work I get I first have to load the history list, then modify it and then save it.
3. It seems unnesessary to first load the list just to modify it? At the moment I'm not interested in the contents of the list and the list might be really really long?

I guess that another approach would be to create a cloud function to perform this update but I would like to implement as much as possible in the app. Is there a better approach to what I'äm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a better approach on how to solve this issue. I create a relation table between the user and video. This tables consist of the user, video and when the video was played. I update the list with:

```
- (void)addVideoToHistory:(Video *)video
{
    //Make sure that the user has been saved.
    if(!self.objectId)
    {
        [self saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
        {
            [self addVideoToHistory:video];
        }];

        return;
    }

    //Query for matching videos
    PFQuery *videoQuery = [Video query];
    [videoQuery whereKey:@"videoId" equalTo:video.videoId];

    [videoQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *foundVideo, NSError *errorFetchingVideo)
    {
        __block UserVideoHistory *history = nil;

        //No video found, we know that there cant exist in history. Create a new history object
        if(!foundVideo)
        {
            [video incrementPlayCount];
            history = [UserVideoHistory object];
            [history setUser:self];
            [history setVideo:video];
            [history setPlayedAt:[NSDate date]];
            [history saveEventually];
        }
        else
        {
            //Query for existing video in history for the current user
            PFQuery *historyQuery = [UserVideoHistory query];
            [historyQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:self];
            [historyQuery whereKey:@"video" equalTo:foundVideo];
            [historyQuery includeKey:@"video"];

            [historyQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *errorFetchingHistory)
            {
                //If we have an existing history we just update the playedAt date, otherwise we create a new history
                if(object)
                {
                    history = (UserVideoHistory *) object;
                }
                else
                {
                    history = [UserVideoHistory object];
                    [history setUser:self];
                    [history setVideo:(Video *) foundVideo];
                }

                [history.video incrementPlayCount];
                [history setPlayedAt:[NSDate date]];

                [history saveEventually];
                [history.video saveEventually];
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```